# Black screen in ios9 using ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Ipad having ios 9 shows a brief black screen.I have added the patch released by ionic but still the issue is not solved.Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who look here the issue can be resolved using css

```
[nav-view-transition="ios"][nav-view-direction="forward"], [nav-view-transition="ios"][nav-view-direction="back"] {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```